# Protect against silent1.pl Perl Script

Tags: security, shell, perl, exploit

I operate a small shared hosting area. While I notice that people are unable/struggle to exploit with PHP I have found a small minority of people using Perl in order to obtain server information.

So, to put it simply here is the question I would like to ask -

Is there a way to prevent Perl scripts from accessing certain system critical files such as named.conf /etc/passwd & others? Naturally suhosin/ suphp or php.ini does not protect against this when in a perl scenario.

Answer (score 5):

[chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) the users and/or Apache (
[example 1](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/chroot-apache-under-rhel-fedora-centos-linux.html)
[example 2](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/36331), 
[example 3](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap29sec254.html)
)

Comment: I suggest chrooting both, as well as bind and any other public facing services.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I cannot agree more. Just one issue, I am running a cPanel/ LiteSpeed setup. While I am sure LiteSpeed will run within the chroot fine, cPanel not so much!